# Extra White Space on Right Page CSS/HTML

Tags: css, whitespace

Good Day Im new to CSS
And recently after I have finish my first project, an extra white space came up on my page, Then I have found out that the `hr` tag that I am using is one reason why there an extra white space(I guess?) , when I put `hr` size

```css
#hr{
    width:960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    height: 12px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

white page will appear

But when I put

```css
#hr {
    width:70%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    height: 12px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will be ok but zooming it in/out will move the hr line,

If needed I'll post the codes but my codes is so many...

---

Right, I think ill put my codes,

HTML CODES:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Beginner</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="top-most">

</div>


<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo">

    <img alt="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
</div>

<div id="header">
    <p>info@CreativeStudio.com</p>
</div>

    <div id="top-bar-selection" >
    <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> ABOUT US </a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html"> SERVICES </a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html"> BLOG </a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> CONTACT US </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<hr id="hr" />

<div id="banner">

        <object id="flash1" data="Beginner.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 960px; height: 380px">
            <param name="movie" value="Beginner.swf" />
        </object>
</div>

<div id="hr2">
    <hr /> 
</div>

<div id="information">

<div id="about-us-section">
    <div id="about-us"> 
    <h3>&#8594;&nbsp; ABOUT US</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="hr">
    <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis nulla id orci malesuada porta posuere quis massa. Nunc vitae purus non augue scelerisque ulitricies vitae et velit. Sed vitae lectus id sem lobortis scelerisque. Praesent eget consequat libero.</p>
     <p style="height: 3px"></p>&#8594;<h4><a href="About.html">Read</a></h4>
    </div>
</div>

     <div id="our-benefits-section">
        <div id="our-benefits">
        <h3>&#8594;&nbsp; OUR BENEFITS</h3> 
        </div>  
        <div id="hr">
        <hr /> 
</div>

    <div id="content">

    <p>&#9745;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis nulla id orci malesuada porta posuere quis massa. </p>

    <p>&#9745; Nunc vitae purus non augue scelerisque ulitricies vitae et velit. Sed vitae lectus id sem lobortis scelerisque. Praesent eget consequat</p>

    <p>&#9745;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis nulla id orci malesuada porta posuere quis massa. </p>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="testimonials-section">
    <div id="testimonials">
        <h3>&#8594;&nbsp; TESTIMONIALS</h3>
    </div>      

<div id="hr">
    <hr /> 
</div>

        <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis nulla id orci malesuada porta posuere quis massa. Nunc vitae purus non augue scelerisque ulitricies vitae et velit. Sed vitae lectus id sem lobortis scelerisque. Praesent eget consequat libero.</p> 
    <h5>Rafi, Graphicsfuel.com</h5></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="hr">
    <hr /> 
</div>

<div id="our-portfolio-section">

    <div id="our-portfolio">
        <h3>&#8594;&nbsp; OUR PORTFOLIO</h3>
    </div>      

        <img alt="PortfolioA" src="images/Portfolio A.jpg" id ="picA" />
        <img alt="PortfolioB" src="images/Portfolio B.jpg" id ="picB"/>
        <img alt="PortfolioC" src="images/Portfolio C.jpg" id ="picC"/>
        <img alt="PortfolioD" src="images/Portfolio D.jpg" id ="picD"/>

</div>

<div id="hr">
    <hr /> 
</div>
<div id="information2">

<div id="blog-updates-section">

<div id="blog-updates">
    <h4>&#8594;&nbsp; BLOG UPDATES</h4>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis nulla id orci malesuada porta posuere quis massa. Nunc vitae purus non augue scelerisque ulitricies vitae et velit. Sed vitae lectus id sem lobortis scelerisque. Praesent eget consequat libero.</p> 
</div>
</div>

<div id="socialmedia">
<h6> &#8594;&nbsp;CONNECT WITH US</h6>

    <img alt="" src="images/Icon/Twitter.png" />
    <img alt="" src="images/Icon/Facebook.png" />
    <img alt="" src="images/Icon/Flickr.png" />
    <img alt="" src="images/Icon/RSS.png" />

    </div>


</div>

<div id="footerbgcolor">

<div id="footer">
    <div class="below-bar-selection">
            <p>Home | <a href="about.html">About Us</a> | <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a> | <a href="services.html">Services</a> | <a href="blog.html">Blog</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></p>
            <p>&copy; 2010 CreativeStudio. All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-small" style="left: 770px; top: 1240px; width: 128px"> 
    <img alt="" src="images/Icon/Logo%20Small.png" />
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODES:

```
#top-most           { background-color:black; height:17px; }

#wrapper            { width :960px; height:130px ; margin:0px auto; background-color: #F4F4F4; overflow:hidden;  }

#logo               { margin: 19px 0 0 10px; float:left; }

#header             { float: right; margin: 19px 3px 0 0;  }
#header p           { color: #979899; }

#top-bar-selection  { width:960px;position :absolute ; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block; margin:70px auto 0 -160px; word-spacing:1px; letter-spacing:1px;}

#top-bar-selection ul{color:orange;  text-align: right;  }
#top-bar-selection ul li {display :inline; font-size:12px;  font-family: arial black; margin: 0 32px 0 0;}
#top-bar-selection ul li a:link {color: #fe9a00; font-family: Arial black; }
#top-bar-selection ul li a:hover {color: #000000; font-family: Arial black; }

#hr { width: auto;  margin: 0px auto; color:#C0C0C0; height: 12px; margin-bottom:15px; overflow:hidden;}

#hr2                { width:960px; margin: 0px auto ; margin-top:10px; height:9px;}

#banner             { width:960px; height:380px ; margin:0px auto; background-color: black; }



#information        { width:960px; margin :0px auto 0 auto; height:235px; padding-top : 15px; margin-top:13px; }



#about-us-section   { width: 266px; margin-right: 600px; background-color: #F4F4F4; position:absolute;  padding-right: 10px; }

#about-us-section hr    { background-color:black; height:7px; width:260px; margin:10px 0 0 0; position:absolute;    }

#about-us-section  p { padding-top: 10px;  font-weight:lighter;}

#about-us-section h4 {  color:#FF9933; display:inline;  line-height:30px;}
#about-us-section h4 a:link {color: #fe9a00; font-family: Arial black; }
#about-us-section h4 a:active {color: #fe9a00; font-family: Arial black;}
#about-us-section h4 a:visited {color: #fe9a00; font-family: Arial black;}
#about-us-section h4 a:hover { color:#000000; }



#our-benefits-section   { width: 270px;  margin: 0 0 0 355px; background-color  : #F4F4F4; position:absolute; padding-right: 10px;}

#our-benefits-section hr    { background-color:black; height:7px; width:260px; margin:10px 0 0 0; position:absolute;    }

#our-benefits-section p     { padding-top: 10px; }




#testimonials-section   { width: 270px; margin: 0 0 0 700px;  position:absolute; padding-right: 10px;  }

#testimonials-section hr    { background-color:black; height:7px; width:260px; margin:10px 0 0 0;   position:absolute; }

#testimonials-section p     { padding-top: 10px; font-weight:300; }

#testimonials-section h5        { padding-top: 10px; font-style:italic; }



#our-portfolio-section  { width:960px; margin: 0px auto 0 auto;  display: block; height:205px; }

#our-portfolio-section our-portfolio { margin: 5px 2px 0 0; }

#our-portfolio-section img  { padding: 15px; display:inline;}




#information2       { width:960px; margin :0px auto 0 auto; height:145px; margin-top:5px; }

#blog-updates-section { width:600px; height:50px; position:absolute; }

#blog-updates-section h3 {margin: 8px 5px 0 0; line-height:10px;}

#blog-updates-section p {margin: 28px 5px 0 0; }


#blog-updates .content  { margin: 28px 5px 0 0; float:left; position:absolute;}



#socialmedia    { float:right; overflow:hidden; position:absolute;margin: 10px 720px; width: 150px; height: 125px; width:200px;}

#socialmedia h6 { font-size:10px;}

#socialmedia img { padding: 6px; margin-top:20px; }




#footerbgcolor  { background-color:#E2E2E2; height:100px; }

#footer     { width :960px; height:100px ; overflow:hidden; margin:0px auto; }

#footer .below-bar-selection { margin: 30px  0 0 20px; float:left; width: 750px; }


#footer a:link {color: #000000; font-family: Arial black; }
#footer a:active {color: #000000; font-family: Arial black;}
#footer a:visited {color: #000000; font-family: Arial black;}
#footer h4 a:hover { color:#000000; font-family:Arial black;}

#footer .logo-small { float:right; padding-top: 15px;}
```

Comment: Without your HTML, no one can help. Have you given your hr an ID of "hr"? Otherwise your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already got a better solution, then forget this message,

But i noticed something.

according to your code

```
#hr { 
width: auto;  
margin: 0px auto; 
color:#C0C0C0; 
height: 12px; 
margin-bottom:15px; 
overflow:hidden;}
```

Since your id of Wrapper is 960 pixels, 
use that width template to set your HR' width value.

so change:

```
width: auto;
```

to

```
width: 958px;
```

Notice: 960px looks a bit too long, so i shaved some pixels out to fit the alignment. But if 960 looks better, then choose 960.

Comment: my friend, I apologize. I don't know what else to say. Maybe someone else can spot why it is doing that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all i don't see any white space on right side of the page rather space between the hr tag due to the height you have given.

Secondly,

hr tag will automatically create a line. If you want to give it an id that means you want to add additional styling to the hr element.

If i am understanding properly, than you shouldn't even use WIDTH.

```
      #hr{
// no need to use width as it will automatcally fill it self
    margin: 0px auto;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    height: 12px; // only needed if you want to create space inbetween
    margin-bottom:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and use it as

```
<hr id="hr" />
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only posted the CSS code without the HTML code, it may be hard for people to see the whole problem, but from the information you posted, this will be my proposed solution,

This css code:

```
width:960px;
```

makes your HR a fixed width of 960 pixels.

This css code:

```
width:70%;
```

makes your HR take up 70% of its container's width.

You could just try setting the width to 100%.

p.s. Why do you need it to be 70% ?

Answer (score 0):

```
hr { //remove # so it will apply to <hr> tag
    width:70%;
    margin: 10px auto; // change the margin size so the hr line can be seen
    color:#C0C0C0;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I think the problem that could remove the hr line is only about margin. If the margin is set to 0, then the hr line could be override by another tag